# custom exception handling database insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I hope you understand me

I have  2 questions

1 How do I implement custom exception handling ?

2 I have my this table

ID
ExceptionName
ClassName
MethodName
FieldName
ErrorMessage

I want to record following for a exception to the table :
what was the error page? 
what was the error classname?
what was the error method and What was the name of the fieldname ? How can I get Exception details?
Get Class Name and Method Name Where Exception Occurred From Exception Details

MSSQL + C# mvc framework 4.0

thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is the function which you have to call inside your catch block,

```
 public static void LogException(Exception exc, string source)
{
    // Include enterprise logic for logging exceptions 
    // Get the absolute path to the log file 
    string logFile = "App_Data/ErrorLog.txt";
    logFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logFile);

    // Open the log file for append and write the log
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true);
    sw.WriteLine("********** {0} **********", DateTime.Now);
    if (exc.InnerException != null)
    {
        sw.Write("Inner Exception Type: ");
        sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.GetType().ToString());
        sw.Write("Inner Exception: ");
        sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.Message);
        sw.Write("Inner Source: ");
        sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.Source);
        if (exc.InnerException.StackTrace != null)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Inner Stack Trace: ");
            sw.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    sw.Write("Exception Type: ");
    sw.WriteLine(exc.GetType().ToString());
    sw.WriteLine("Exception: " + exc.Message);
    sw.WriteLine("Source: " + source);
    sw.WriteLine("Stack Trace: ");
    if (exc.StackTrace != null)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

refer to the link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417(v=vs.140).aspx